# How to add a new line AFTER a line that begins with a specific string?

Tags: notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ and was curious if there is an easy way to add a new line at the end of lines that begin with a specific string?

Example:

I want a line that begins

```
 <property name="Split Rules" value=" ......
```

That value is going to be different for every thing with that property, so I'd like to see the beginning of the line is

```
<property name="Split Rules"
```

and at the end of that line break to a new line and insert a new property document wide.

Is that easily done?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you please display some line that show what you have before and what you want after?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean after every string `<property name="Split Rules"` insert new line, then hit ctrl+h and in `Find what` enter string from above, in `Replace with` enter `<property name="Split Rules" \r\n`. Don't forget to check `search mode` to `extended`